# Object with 8 different value sets

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, object, data-structures

Hello everyone i'm trying to make an object that will show a different set of values based off the index chosen.

```
<script>
    var schedule = {
        max_schedule: 8, // number of schedules
        for (i = 0; i < max_schedule; i++){
            value1[i]: [0, 0, 0],
            value2[i]: [0, 0, 0],
            value3[i]: "",
            value4[i]: "",
            value5[i]: 0,
            value6[i]: 0,
            value7[i]: 0,
            value8[i]: 0,
            value9[i]: false
        }
    };
</script>
```

I am unsure how to do this as trying to create an object while using a for-loop seems to lead to syntactical errors

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please explain what you want the object to look like, this is not how Objects work in JS

Comment: @LucaKiebel and ArayniMax is there any reason the following website shows javascript objects defined this way then? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: This page doesn't show Objects being defined the way you define them.

Comment: I believe that it shows them defined exactly how I defined them with the exception of my for-loop, as you can see member variables are defined there using ":" instead of "=" like my above sample code. I guess my issue was how I could use a for-loop to create several schedules https://i.gyazo.com/14d02af7755a4a94d6379e414a185507.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```js
var schedule = {
        max_schedule: 8, // number of schedules
        
    };
    
    for (i = 0; i < schedule.max_schedule; i++){
            schedule['value1'+i]= [0, 0, 0],
            schedule['value2'+i]= [0, 0, 0],
            schedule['value3'+i]= "",
            schedule['value4'+i]= "",
            schedule['value5'+i]= 0,
            schedule['value6'+i]= 0,
            schedule['value7'+i]= 0,
            schedule['value8'+i]= 0,
            schedule['value9'+i]= false
        }
        
        console.log(schedule)
```

Comment: Yes that is perfect thank you kindly I've been having a bit of confusion of how objects and structures behave a bit differently in this language I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

JS objects do not work like that. Do some further research, is pretty important to know how objects work since they are an essential part of JavaScript.

About your issue, i think this is what you are trying to do. I guess you receive those values from a database and then you want to set a number of schedules and create the object based on that number.
Check this

```js
var values = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], "", "", 0, 0, 0, 0, false];
var schedule = {};
var max_schedule = 8;

for(var index = 0; index < max_schedule; index++) {
  schedule['value' + index] = values[index];
}

console.log(schedule);
```